# Angular 2 pipe -data is not getting passed into transform method

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to implement a very simple pipe which takes data from *ngFor and then do some operation ,however when i am doing data.filter() its throwing an error "cannot read property filter of undfined"

**here is my pipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'tripFilterByStartDate',pure: false  })
export class tripFilterByStartDateModule implements PipeTransform {
transform(values: any, args: any[] = null) {
    console.log(values);//
    return values.filter(value => value.someValue);// throwing an error "cannot read property filter of undefined" 
  }
}
```

**and here is my html page**

```
 <ion-card *ngFor="let tripData of tripList | tripFilterByStartDate" text-wrap>

 </ion-card>
```

any suggestion would be of great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cannot read property filter of undefined` error clearly stated that your `values` object isn't exists(undefined) when your Pipe got called on initial Change detection. From Pipe `filter` method got applied over `values` variable. Since `tripList` haven't got retrieved list from server, it got failed(also `impure` pipe gets called on each `tick`).

So you should handle this situation in your filter itself.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'tripFilterByStartDate',pure: false  })
export class tripFilterByStartDateModule implements PipeTransform {
transform(values: any, args: any[] = null) {
    if(!values) return []; //added this line
    return values.filter(value => value.someValue);// throwing an error "cannot read property filter of undefined" 
  }
}
```